# What are the pros and cons of using `Object.create` vs direct assignment when creating prototype chains in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

```
function Foo() {};
function Bar() { Foo.call(this) };
function Baz() { Foo.call(this) };

Bar.prototype = Foo.prototype;
Bar.prototype.constructor = Bar;

Baz.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
Baz.prototype.constructor = Baz;

Foo.prototype.fiz = 'asdf';

console.log(Bar.prototype);
//=> Foo { fiz: 'asdf' }

console.log(Baz.prototype);
//=> Foo {}
```

It seems that given the above code and output of `Bar.prototype` vs `Baz.prototype` that if you wish the inherited prototype to automatically contain properties and methods set at runtime or after the inheritance process using direct assignment is preferred. However, I've seen the use of `Object.create` more often as an example of correct prototypal inheritance. Yet, we can see that the prototype of `Baz` doesn't get updated and would have to be modified "manually" to reflect any changes made to `Foo.prototype` after inheritance takes place (or at runtime).

Is there another argument against direct assignment that I'm missing? A reason why `Object.create(Foo.prototype)` is preferred over just assigning an inheriting constructor's prototype directly to `Foo.prototype`?